# Android app is not published in alpha test mode

Tags: android, release, in-app-billing, alpha, subscription

Application is rejected from the play store.
So, I have uploaded app in alpha testing for implementing a subscription, still we are not able to see opt-in the link for the tester.

Instead of an opt-in link, we only able to see "An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app."

For this reason, I am not able to test subscription. Getting error code 6.

[image: Play store console[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMtJn.png)

Subscription Error:
[image]